# WordPress the_permalink() outputting nothing

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I can outputting all of my posts in a custom post type called Featured Projects.
The outputting of the psots work fine, as do the custom post values from the custom meta box.
What doesn't output is the_permalink() and the_title(). They are just blank.

If you have any clue what I screwed up or what I can check, I would appreciate it!

```
<ul id="projects-nav">
  <?php query_posts('post_type=featured-projects&order=ASC&orderby=menu_order&posts_per_page=-1'); ?>
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php $agency = get_post_custom_values('agency'); ?>
  <?php $production = get_post_custom_values('production'); ?>
  <?php $post = get_post_custom_values('post'); ?>
  <?php $video_url = get_post_custom_values('video_url_1'); ?>
  <?php $thumb_url = get_post_custom_values('thumb_url_1'); ?>
  <li>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" src="<?php echo $thumb_url[0]; ?>" width="185" height="113"></a>
  <h4><?php the_title(''); ?></h4>
  <?php the_content(""); ?>
  <?php if($agency[0] != '') { ?><p>Agency: <?php echo $agency[0]; ?></p><?php } ?>
  <?php if($production[0] != '') { ?><p>Production: <?php echo $production[0]; ?></p><?php } ?>
  <?php if($post[0] != '') { ?><p>Post: <?php echo $post[0]; ?></p><?php } ?>
 </li>
 <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of headaches and thrashing around and trying lots of different things. For some reason changing the placement of the variables seemed to make it all work.
The final code ended up being

```
<ul id="projects-nav">
  <?php query_posts('post_type=projects&order=ASC&orderby=menu_order'); ?>
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php $thumb_url = get_post_custom_values('thumb_url_1'); ?>
  <li> 
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img alt="<?php the_title(''); ?>" src="<?php echo $thumb_url[0]; ?>" width="185" height="113"></a>
        <h4><?php the_title(''); ?></h4>
        <?php the_content(''); ?>

    <?php $agency = get_post_custom_values('agency'); ?>
    <?php $production = get_post_custom_values('production'); ?>
    <?php $post = get_post_custom_values('post'); ?>
        <?php if($agency[0] != '') { ?><p>Agency: <?php echo $agency[0]; ?></p><?php } ?>
        <?php if($production[0] != '') { ?><p>Production: <?php echo $production[0]; ?></p><?php } ?>
        <?php if($post[0] != '') { ?><p>Post: <?php echo $post[0]; ?></p><?php } ?>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Thanks to everyone else who tried to help!!

Answer (score 0):

For the permalink, you can use the following alternative:

Also did you try removing the quotes inside the ? That could be messing with it.

Comment: What alternative? What quotes?

Comment: Your the_title element that is surrounded by the h4 tag has quotes inside the parenthesis. Maybe try removing them.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should first try to get posts from `$agency` only then if it works try `$production`.

i don't think it know `the_title()` of what custom post type to get. try the whole thing with 1 custom post type first then add. my $0.02

Comment: The custom post values: agency, production, video, thumbnail and post production varaiables all work just fine. It's the the_permalink, the_title, and the_content that don't output anything. There is only one custom post type, Featured Projects, that's what's being queried in query_posts()

Comment: Okay, just realized that the_content() is outputting, but the_title and the_permalink and get_permalink don't work.